# Can't install Elementary OS, Grub error

Tags: uefi, grub

For some reason, I can't install Elementary OS, At the end of installing the OS, it comes up with an error:

`Grub-pc failed to install to /target/`

Also to note, I have no internet connection for another odd reason. I'm currently connected with Ethernet on windows, but nothing on the Elementary installation.